# No resource found error while calling WEB API

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I created a WEB API for getting some list . I created another API for login which is working fine. But whenever call the API which provide me some list, it will show error as 
**No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:85476/API/EmployeeMobile/GetEmployeeForMobile**,
**No action was found on the controller 'EmployeeMobile' that matches the request.**

**My controller**:

```
 public class EmployeeMobileController : ApiController
    {

        private PCommon _pCommon;
        IEmployeeBusiness _employeeBusiness;
        Mapper _mapper;
        public EmployeeMobileController()
        {
            _pCommon = new PCommon();
            _employeeBusiness = new EmployeeBusiness();

            _mapper = new Mapper();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public string GetEmployeeForMobile(string userID, string connectionString)
        {
            DataSet dsEmployee = _employeeBusiness.GetAllEmployeeForMobile(Guid.Parse(userID), connectionString);
            JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            object routes_list = (object)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dsEmployee.Tables[0]));
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(routes_list);
        }
    }
```

**My WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
```

**My PostMan Calling details**

http://localhost:61557/API/EmployeeMobile/GetEmployeeForMobile

`Body: {"userID":"fc938df0-373c559f","connectionString":"Data\tSource=WIN\\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial\tCatalog=PDefault;User\tID=db;Password=db123"`}

Please help me to recover this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, `WebAPI` doesn't support binding of multiple `POST` parameters. You are defining your `POST` like a `GET` method. Change it to return a single Model

Your model should look like following.

```
 public class Input
    {
        public string uSerID { get; set; }
        public string connectionString { get; set; }
    }
```

Now change the POST method like

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string GetEmployeeForMobile(Input request)
  {
   //Your implementation here
  }
```

and you `JSON` for the post should look like following.

```
{uSerID:"abc", connectionString :"xyz"}
```

Comment: Thanks bro..You saved my life. I understand my mistakes.Thanks again.